# "no license is defined ..." or "no licenses are defined ..."

Tags: grammatical-number, negation

Should I say "no license is defined for ..." or "no licenses are defined for ..."? If both are correct, which are preferable?

A quick internet search shows the former is used more frequently. Yet, perhaps, the latter better reflect the fact that a thing (e.g. a software package) can be covered by multiple licenses. For example, the same computer software is often distributed both under commercial and open-source licenses, where a commercial license might offers better support and accountability for damages.

Comment: They look the same to me

Comment: Both are the same... 

Comment: Use the first one. (An ellipsis only has three dots.)

Comment: In broad terms,  "**a** commercial license", "**a**" = "**an example of a**"  -- "commercial licenses" = "all commercial licenses"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the singular "is" and "license" when I wish to say that one license, which is the expected or customary number, is not defined. I would use the plural "are" and "licenses" when I wish to say that no licenses at all (when one or more might have existed) are defined.

Comment: Note: US spelling is 'license' for both verb and noun; UK/British English zone spelling is 'license' for the verb and 'licence' for the noun.